# Editing non-ASCII text in Vim vs Emacs

Tags: vim, emacs, utf-8

I have spent several hours reading and searching for the difference between vim and emacs as I am considering learning one of these in order to edit multiple text files written in Thai. My question is:

Given that navigation and editing are done via key stroke combinations, are either of these editors practical for editing of non-Latin files, and if so, which has the upper hand for this specific task, and why?

I would also like to batch apply search/replace regex over multiple files.

**Edit:** The files are all UTF-8. Some are LaTeX files, others are text files and html files. The primary editing will be of the Thai text itself. I also have a few Lao files that I will be editing as well and I see a future use for editing Greek and Khmer.

Comment: In what character set are these file written to disk? Is it in UTF-8, or some other format?

Comment: Can't you just *try* them?

Comment: 'Non-ASCII' text is too broad. For example, I imagine you can edit Russian text quite conveniently in Vim, but you cannot edit Devanagari text at all (in my experience). Whether or not Vim is suited for Thai is yet another question.

Comment: @Verhagen—The character set of these files are UTF-8.

Comment: @romaini — Since I don't know either Vim or emacs, and since there is a learning curve, I want to know proof of concept first and then have some feedback from people who actually use either Vim or emacs for editing of non-ASCII text.

Comment: @gits — My apologies if the question is vague. I wanted my question to be beneficial to a wider audience who might also have the same question regarding their language. Your answer is helpful, and at the same time curious. Since vim and emacs both use ascii key combinations for navigation, I assumed that editing any non-ascii text might be problematic. I find it helpful that text in Cyrillic is edited easily while Hindi or Nepalese cannot be. Although not mentioned in my question, I do have text in Lao and in the future, possibly Khmer that will needed edited as well.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs has extensive multilingual text editing supports, including a large library of input methods (e.g., thai-kesmanee, thai-pattachote), and tools for working with various character sets and encodings (utf-8, tis620, etc.).

Once you start Emacs, you can type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> to check if you have the necessary fonts installed for the desired script, and <kbd>C-\</kbd> to toggle specialized input method.

Comment: Thank you. I have been burning the midnight oil and taking the "taste and see" approach suggested by @romaini above, starting with vim (although I still don't have a proof of concept.) My arthritis has me fearful of emacs heavy dependence on the control key, but perhaps that is unwarranted. However, with your assurance that Thai input works with emacs, I will definitely be trying emacs.

Answer (score 0):

"Can't you just try them?" @romainl said.

2 1/2 months later the answer for vim is a resounding YES.

Extensive mapping in the vimrc file and I can navigate and edit Thai texts while in the Thai keyboard faster than I could edit in a word processor in my previous life.

The only issues with vim so far are text wrapping and single word navigation/edits. Apparently both of these could be fixed by someone kindly patching vim with ICU bindings.

I can not speak as to which has the upper hand, but only say that vim works well for this. Apparently emacs does too.